# htaccess: add php extension, except when there is a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

I understand that to hide a website extension, I can use the following regular expression in htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite, e.g., `example.com\post` to `example.com\post.php`.

However, how do I modify the script such that it DOES NOT add `.php` when there is a trailing slash at the end? This is so that it will recognise the index page.

Currently, if I have `example.com\folder\`, it will rewrite it as `example.com\folder\.php`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another `RewriteCond` to check the URI for a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You can find a working example of this here:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d1fa1042-e671-5b7d-ba96-572510689e8b

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly checking for a trailing slash the usual approach is to check if the request actually references a directory in the server side file system. That can be implemented like this, which also checks if such a php file actually does exist:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).